# Modify Select2 search box

Tags: javascript, templates, jquery-select2

I am using the ajax feature of the [Select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax) control to load the options asynchronously. However, I would like to change the default template of the search box to have a placeholder and an icon on the right.

Is there a proper way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Placeholder:**
From the example:

```
$(".js-example-placeholder-single").select2({
  placeholder: "Select a state",
  allowClear: true
});
```

**Custom Icon:**

You can append it using JS. Simply create a DOM element, append it where you want and style it with CSS. Of course you can also add its additional functionality if needed.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp